# MongoDB upsert into array of elements

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I have a collection ("sheets") with documents in this structure:

```
{
  _id: "xxx",
  name: "yyy",
  cells: [
    {
      x: 0, y: 0, sheet_id: "xxx", data: {content: "hello", type: "string"}
    },
    {
      x: 0, y: 1, sheet_id: "xxx", data: {content: "hello 2", type: "string"}
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a compound unique index for cells.x + cells.y + cells.sheet_id
with partial `{ 'cells.x': { $exists: true } }`

I want to insert or update an object in the *cells* array.

```
const result = await db.collection("sheets").updateOne(
    { _id: "xxx", 'cells.x': 0, 'cells.y': 1 },
    {
        $set: {
            'cells.$.sheetId': "xxx",
            'cells.$.x': 0,
            'cells.$.y': 1,
            'cells.$.data': {type: "string", content: "hello 3"},
        },
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

with this update, if an element with matching x, y and sheet_id exists, it updates it correctly.
but if it does not exists, for example:

```
$set: {
    'cells.$.sheetId': "xxx",
    'cells.$.x': 50,
    'cells.$.y': 100,
    'cells.$.data': {type: "string", content: "hello NEW"}
}
```

I get error:
`MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query`

how can I make it so:

- a "new" cell will be inserted into the *cells* array when no cell with a matching x-y-sheet_id was found.
- but a cell with matching x-y-sheet_id will be updated without inserting a new '*cell*.